# CastleWindsor dependency injection in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, castle-windsor

we try at the moment to migrate an application from a very old .NET Core 1.1 to .NET 6. In this application we are using `CastleWindsor 4.1.1` as dependency injection framework. Now we are at the point where we have to write the initialization to the new .NET Web API handling in the `Program.cs` but all we found ends with .NET Framework. Is CastleWindsor still supported in .NET and when yes, is there somewhere a migration guide?

Comment: You can use [Castle.Windsor.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Castle.Windsor.Extensions.DependencyInjection) to adapt the standard .NET DI mechanism to use Castle.Windsor. There seems to be a boatload of potential duplicate to this question. You might search StackOverflow also.

Comment: [Windor's repo page describes it as "Mature" and lists a lot of features unsupported when running it on a .NET Standard target](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor) - which implies it should works in .NET 6... but only for the most basic use-cases.

Comment: As @Dai indicated, please note advanced Windsor features (like named dependencies for example), will not be accessible if you only use `IServiceProvder.GetService...` to resolve dependencies or `ServiceCollection.Add...` to register services. This is so, because those types simply don't have an API surface for such features. It does work though, if you are willing to use Castle.Windsor specific APIs in your code (lookup and registration).